# Add Next line in Table group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to move next line in table in ssrs reports.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not clear from your question what the problem is. Is the image the result you want or what you have now? Also share sample data and report design showing any row and/or column groups that you have. Please **EDIT** your question to  provide more info.

Comment: There's not an easy way to do this. I think the easiest way to do this is to use a subreport for the list of codes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833487/ssrs-report-badges/68837635#68837635 will help with how to do the code matrix.